# For SQL SERVER how do I call $PARTITION with dynamically computed partition function?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to do the equivalent of

`SET @partitionIndex = EXEC('$PARTITION.' + @partitionFunction + '(' + @date +')')`

But EXEC can't be treated as a function.  Do I need to create a temporary table and select into it or something or is there some more direct way of getting the value?

I tried the command given above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.sp_executesql` with an `OUTPUT` parameter

```
DECLARE @partitionFunction SYSNAME = 'pf1'
DECLARE @Date DATE = '1900-01-01'

DECLARE @PNumber INT

DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT @PNumber = $PARTITION.' + QUOTENAME(@partitionFunction) + '(@Date)'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql
  @DynSql,
  N'@Date DATE, @PNumber INT OUTPUT',
  @Date = @Date,
  @PNumber = @PNumber OUTPUT

SELECT @PNumber AS [@PNumber]
```

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't work with `DECLARE @i int, @proc nvarchar(max) = '$PARTITION.' + QUOTENAME(@partitionFunction); EXEC @i = @proc '20220101';` even though this works with regular scalar functions

Comment: @Charlieface - yeah you can't `EXEC` built in functions. Which is presumably why this is the only case where SQL Server also allows you to call scalar UDFs with a one part name (there is no possible ambiguity with built in ones here)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to do this without dynamic SQL, although the value in doing so is questionable.

```sql
SELECT
  ISNULL(r.boundary_id, f.fanout)
FROM sys.partition_functions f 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      r.boundary_id
    FROM sys.partition_range_values r
    WHERE r.function_id = f.function_id
      AND (
        f.boundary_value_on_right = 0 AND (
          @d <= r.value OR
          @d IS NULL
        )
        OR f.boundary_value_on_right = 1 AND (
          @d < r.value OR
          @d IS NULL AND r.value IS NOT NULL
        )
      )
    ORDER BY
      r.boundary_id
) r
WHERE f.name = @partitionFunction;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A2Ji89Cs)

Note the careful usage of range boundaries for both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` ranges, especially where nulls are involved.

If you know upfront whether the function is `LEFT` or `RIGHT`, or that nulls are not involved, then you can elide those parts.

Comment: This was actually useful as it showed me how to get an explicit table mapping index to boundary value which I can use for testing.